# Convert an array which contains strings into key value pairs

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string, maps

I have a string "101-2000-10-102-2000-15" which I have to map as key: 101 values: {2000, 10}.
With the below code I am able to get the output as 101 => 2000 but I am unable to the one remaining value.
This is the Code:

```
let myString = "101-2000-10-102-2000-15"
let strArray = myString.match(/[^-]+-[^-]+-[^-]+/g);
console.log(strArray);
let compartmentMap = new Map(strArray.map(x => x.split("-")));
console.log(compartmentMap);
```

My input: "101-2000-10-102-2000-15"
Desired Output: {101 => {2000,10}, 102 => {2000,15}}

Answer (score 2):

You need to get an array of values as well.

```js
let myString = "101-2000-10-102-2000-15"
let strArray = myString.match(/[^-]+-[^-]+-[^-]+/g);
console.log(strArray);
let compartmentMap = new Map(strArray.map(x => {
    const [k, ...v] = x.split("-");
    return [k, v];
}));

console.log(Array.from(compartmentMap));
```

Answer (score 2):

I think I'd be fairly pedestrian about it:

```
const result = new Map();
const rex = /(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)/g;
let match;
while ((match = rex.exec(myString)) !== null) {
    result.set(match[1], [match[2], match[3]]);
}
```

That's assuming you want the `2000, 10` part as an array.

Live Example:

```js
const myString = "101-2000-10-102-2000-15"
const result = new Map();
const rex = /(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)/g;
let match;
while ((match = rex.exec(myString)) !== null) {
    result.set(match[1], [match[2], match[3]]);
}
console.log([...result.entries()]);
```

Or with more meaningful names via named capture groups and destructuring:

```
const result = new Map();
const rex = /(?<key>\d+)-(?<value1>\d+)-(?<value2>\d+)/g;
let match;
while ((match = rex.exec(myString)) !== null) {
    const {key, value1, value2} = match.groups;
    result.set(key, [value1, value2]);
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const myString = "101-2000-10-102-2000-15"
const result = new Map();
const rex = /(?<key>\d+)-(?<value1>\d+)-(?<value2>\d+)/g;
let match;
while ((match = rex.exec(myString)) !== null) {
    const {key, value1, value2} = match.groups;
    result.set(key, [value1, value2]);
}
console.log([...result.entries()]);
```

Or with the new [`matchAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) and destructuring:

```
const rex = /(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)/g;
const result = new Map(
    [...myString.matchAll(rex)].map(
        ([, key, value1, value2]) => [key, [value1, value2]]
    )
);
```

Live Example:

```js
const myString = "101-2000-10-102-2000-15"
const rex = /(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)/g;
const result = new Map(
    [...myString.matchAll(rex)].map(
        ([, key, value1, value2]) => [key, [value1, value2]]
    )
);
console.log([...result.entries()]);
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to just split the string, and then perform a `reduce()` operation for every three elements:

```js
const s = '101-2000-10-102-2000-15';

const result = s.split('-').reduce((r, v, i, a) =>
    i % 3 ? r : {...r, [v]: a.slice(i + 1, i + 3)}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Slight change to your code, use `reduce` instead of `map`.

```js
let myString = "101-2000-10-102-2000-15";
let strArray = myString.match(/[^-]+-[^-]+-[^-]+/g);
console.log(strArray);
let compartmentMap = strArray.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const [a, b, c] = curr.split("-");
  return Object.assign(acc, { [a]: [b, c] });
}, {});
console.log(compartmentMap);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I figured a better which gives out a Map with exact key-value pairs. All I need is to pass a Map and My array to it and it spits out the map with the key-values.

```
const myString = '101-2000-10-102-2000-15';
let strArray = myString.match(/[^-]+-[^-]+-[^-]+/g);
console.log(strArray);
const compartmentMap = (someMap, someArray) => (someArray.map(x => { console.log(x)
const [a, b, c] = x.split("-");
someMap.set(a, {b,c});
}));
const x = new Map();
compartmentMap(x, strArray);
console.log(x);
```